# JSON RESPONSE BRINGING LIST in response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Need help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu0EK.jpg)

Image of jquery having JSON response

I have a list that is coming in json response I want to access that list so that I can traverse inside the list and access my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop JSON object like this:

```
$(result).each(function (index, item) {
    console.log(item.GetQuery);
    console.log(item.GridQuery});
}
```

Comment: thanxx for the help

Comment: Pls mark as answer if it helped